# Changing QLabel Text for many QLabels

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, python-3.3, qlabel

I am using Python 3 and Qt5.
I have designed a QWidget with just over 700 QLabels. I need to change them but I would like to do so without having to write over 700 lines to set the text for all of my labels.
I also need to show and hide them at will.

Is there a way I can group them or edit a variable if I have a string of that variable's name?
I'm looking for something like the Matlab 'assignin' function.

The labels are named label_A - label_Z and label_AA - label_ZZ

From the main class
    import ezodf

```
self.ui = AnalysisGui.Ui_Form()
self.ui.setupUi(self)

self.Alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e",
                 "f", "g", "h", "i", "j",
                 "k", "l", "m", "n", "o",
                 "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",
                 "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

for Alpha in self.Alphabet:
    self.ui.findChild(QtGui.QLabel, "label_"+Alpha.upper()).SetText(Alpha.upper()+" ")
    for Beta in self.Alphabet:
        self.ui.findChild(QtGui.QLabel, "label_"+Alpha.upper()+Beta.upper()).SetText(Alpha.upper()+Beta.upper()+" ")
```

This is from the AnalysisGui class showing how the labels are defined

```
self.label_A = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
self.label_A.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n""font: 8pt \"Calibri\";\n""background-image: url(:/Thoth/SeeThrough.png);"))
self.label_A.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_A"))
self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_A, 1, 0, 1, 1)
self.label_B = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
self.label_B.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n""font: 8pt \"Calibri\";\n""background-image: url(:/Thoth/SeeThrough.png);"))
self.label_B.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_B"))
self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_B, 1, 1, 1, 1)
self.label_C = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
self.label_C.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n""font: 8pt \"Calibri\";\n""background-image: url(:/Thoth/SeeThrough.png);"))
self.label_C.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_C"))
self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_C, 1, 2, 1, 1)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is your naming scheme for the labels? Are they all in one parent control or in some complicated structure?

Comment: I have added the naming structure above. I didn't explicitly create them with parent control, but if that is the default in pyqt4 then there is.

Comment: But how did you create the labels?

Comment: I created them in Qt Designer... Took a bit of time.

Comment: how do you hide and unhide a QLabel at the same Grid location?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `QWidget.findChild`

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
try:
    from PyQt4.QtWidgets import *
except ImportError:
    pass


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()

for i in range(26):
    title = chr(ord('A')+i)
    label = QLabel(title, window)
    label.setObjectName("label_"+title)
    layout.addWidget(label)

window.findChild(QLabel, "label_F").setText("test")

window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: I don't know if I did something wrong but it didn't work for me. I get: 
AttributeError: 'Ui_Form' object has no attribute 'findChild'
,at the line: 
self.ui.findChild(QtGui.QLabel, "label_"+Alpha.upper()).SetText(Alpha.upper()+" ")

Comment: @Lex Maybe you can just use `getattr(self.ui, "label_"+Alpha.upper()).setText(Alpha.upper()+" ")`... I will look into your problem more deeply tomorrow, now that I know you use that `ui` thing.